# Create whole directory structure with Talend DI

Tags: sftp, file-transfer, directory-structure, talend

I am looking for a way to create a folder struture with Talend DI (with Talend Studio 5.2.0).

I have a temporary folder containing something like this:

```
/tmp/myjob/type1/file01.txt
/tmp/myjob/type1/file02.txt
/tmp/myjob/type1/file03.txt
/tmp/myjob/type1/fileN.txt
/tmp/myjob/type2/file01.csv
/tmp/myjob/type2/file02.csv
/tmp/myjob/type2/file03.csv
/tmp/myjob/type2/fileN.csv
/tmp/myjob/type3/file01.jpg
/tmp/myjob/type3/file02.jpg
/tmp/myjob/type3/file03.jpg
/tmp/myjob/type3/fileN.jpg
```

I want to transfer the whole directory structure to a remote FTP (ftps) folder.

And the result would be:

```
/destination/type1/file01.txt
/destination/type1/file02.txt
/destination/type1/file03.txt
/destination/type1/fileN.txt
/destination/type2/file01.csv
/destination/type2/file02.csv
/destination/type2/file03.csv
/destination/type2/fileN.csv
/destination/type3/file01.jpg
/destination/type3/file02.jpg
/destination/type3/file03.jpg
/destination/type3/fileN.jpg
```

The idea is to configure a `tFTPPut` in order to take the `/tmp/myjob` as root source folder and the talend component to recreate the whole directory structure in the `destination` (remote) folder.

I tried to put the following lines in the `filemask` property:

```
FileMask                newName
"./type1/*.txt"             ""
"./type1/*.csv"             ""
"./type1/*.jpg"             ""
```

When I execute the job, it make the following error:

```
[statistics] connected
Exception in component tFTPPut_1
2: No such file
```

Anybody knows if it is possible to create such a task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, tFtpPut doesn't give you the possibility to create remote folders. The only workaround you have is to connect via ssh and trig the proper CMD/Bash commands.

About your file mask problem, my advice is to use Perl5 regex syntax to express mask patterns. It's way more powerful, standard and well documented. But if your source structure is quite complex, a better time saving solution could be zipping the whole stuff on the source machine, then ftp the package, finally unzip it (again, via ssh connection) on remote machine.

I know it's not a general solution: as a matter of facts, it's not always possible to ssh on a remote machine. But to my knownledge, it's the only workaround possible atm.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, finally I did the ssh command before to create the folder structure and another after to move the uploaded files to the right directories. For the perl regex syntax, I was using it but I cannot find the way to switch between perl regex and other in tFtpPut component.

Comment: You should see a checkbox labelled 'Use Perl5 Regex Expression as Filemask' just above the 'Files' table. That does the magic.

Comment: There is no such box in the tFTPPut component. But I am using version 5.2.0 of Talend Studio, probably a new functionality.

Comment: Likely it's the case. If you don't plan/need to upgrade to 5.4 very often (read: almost always) you can upgrade the single component. You can download 5.4 just to get the news component, then replace it in your exsisting Talend environment. Close Talend, replace the files and delete the 'tFtpPut' directories deeply inside <WORKSPACE_ROOT>/metadata/.Javajet/... (you'll find two) to force a recompile. Finally, restart Talend.